# i am having npm error while trying to add sass to my vue project

Tags: vue.js, npm, sass

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-cli-plugin-sass-loader - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'vue-cli-plugin-sass-loader@*' is not in
this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-28T23_47_26_128Z-debug-0.log
ERROR  Error: command failed: npm install --loglevel error vue-cli-plugin-sass-loader -D --legacy-peer-deps
Error: command failed: npm install --loglevel error vue-cli-plugin-sass-loader -D --legacy-peer-deps
at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli\lib\util\executeCommand.js:138:16)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
at cp.emit (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)

I tried npm install to get a new lock. JSON file  and node module, but when I tried to run npm install,  I still get huge  npm errors, so that means I can't do npm install in my cd project nor can I add a sass plugin

Comment: No such package exists. The SASS loader is typically installed via `npm install -D sass-loader sass`. https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#pre-processors

Comment: ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                        8:11:56 AM

Syntax Error: ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.   sass has finally gotten into my  dev dependencies but im being hit with this error my friend , thanks for your time in helping me